# RSpec testing of a class which uses a gem object as an instance variable

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I'm pretty new to Rspec and I'm trying to figure out how to write tests for a class that takes an object as a constructor parameter and sets that object to an instance variable. Then it calls that instance variable's object methods in other methods.

Example:

```
class ClassA
  def initialize(string_object, gem_object)
    @instance_variable1 = gem_object
    @string = string_object
  end

  def check_validity?(some_arg)
    unless @instance_variable1.gemObjectMethod1.gemObjectMethod2(some_arg).empty?
      return true
    end
    false
  end
  ..
  ..
end
```

I feel very lost in how to write specifications for this. For one I don't really understand what specifying a constructor actually entails. What I realize is that I'd have to find some way of mocking or stubbing the gem_object I'm getting as argument, but I'm not sure how.

For the next method, what I've tried to this point is:

```
describe '#check_validity?' do
  context 'gets empty list' do
    let (:actual) { subject.check_validity?("sample") }
    before do
      allow(subject).to receive(@instance_variable1.gemObjectMethod1.gemObjectMethod2).with("sample").and_return([])
    end
    it 'returns false' do
      expect(actual).to be false
    end
  end
end
```

But this gives me error relating to my constructor saying that it expected 2 arguments but was given 0.

Any help would be much appreciated! Also, I couldn't really find anything on line about specifying constructors with their arguments mocked. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place or maybe missing something obvious as this is my first experience with BDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSpec, 'receive' is a method that accepts a symbol that represents the name of a method.  (It allows you to chain a 'with' method that accepts the expected list of parameters.)  To fix the before-block you could do this:

```
before do
  allow(subject.instance_variable_get(:@instance_variable1).gemObjectMethod1).to receive(:gemObjectMethod2).with("sample").and_return([])
end
```

The sheer ugliness of that, though, suggests that something is wrong.  And it is.  The code is violating the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) pretty badly and the test is being drawn into it.

As a first attempt to clean it up, you might consider a method that "caches" the results of calling @instance_variable1.gemObjectMethod1.  Let's say that that first method returns an enumerable group of widgets.  You could change your class to include something like this:

```
def check_validity(a_string)
  widgets.gemObjectMethod2(a_string).empty?
end

private

def widgets
  @widgets ||= @instance_variable1.gemObjectMethod1
end
```

Your class still knows a bit too much about the gem object, but now you have broken it down in such a way that you could refactor how you find widgets -- perhaps a different gem or your own implementation of it.  For the purposes of your testing, you can isolate that decision from the test by mocking widgets.

```
let(:gem_widgets) do
  instance_double(GemObjectMethod1ResultClass, gemObjectMethod2: true)
end

before do
  allow(subject).to receive(:widgets).and_return(gem_widgets)
  allow(gem_widgets).to receive(:gemObjectMethod2).with("sample").
    and_return([])
end

it 'should pass with "sample"' do
  expect(actual).to eql true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Do you have a suggestion about how to test the constructor though? I was thinking about testing that an object does not exist before calling new and then it does after and it has the correct instance variables. I'm blanking as to how to test if the object has been created or not.

Comment: What I often do with classes like this is make available the instance variables through attribute readers (e.g., attr_reader :string_object, :gem_object at the top of ClassA).  If you do that then testing the assignment is pretty straightforward -- check the getter method value after instantiation.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a question though. By creating the widgets method, aren't I required to find out exactly what gemObjectMethod1 returns and doesn't that go against the principle of abstraction?

Comment: If you copy/past my idea above then you would be checking to see what gemObjectMethod1 returns, that's true.  I'm not sure that you'd be violating rules of abstraction any more than the pasted code already does -- unless gemObjectMethod2 happens to be a common method available on Enumerable or something similar.  The advantage of using a verifying double (instance_double above) is that it verifies the interface of the class against the method(s) you intend to call; that might be a big deal with a gem.  The alternative would be a generic double('widgets', gemObjectMethod2: true)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks